# Calculating thevenin equivalent for a circuit with resistors in a configuration I don't understand

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, thevenin

Having a hard time working out Thevenin equivalents when I see circuits like this:

V<sub>s</sub> - 30V,
R<sub>1</sub> - 100 ohms,
R<sub>2</sub> - 1000 ohms,
R<sub>3</sub> - 1500 ohms,
R<sub>4</sub> - 900 ohms

[image: Circuit]

So, right off that bat, I'm not sure I understand which resistors are in series or parallel.  I thought that R3 and R4 are in series, and (R3 + R4) is in parallel with R2, and all of that is in series with R1.  It doesn't seem correct, as I end up with the wrong answer.

If I was right, that would make it look like a voltage divider.

So, I come up with:

$$(R3 + R4) || R2 = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1500\Omega + 900\Omega} + \frac{1}{1000\Omega}} = 705.88 \Omega $$

And then to figure out the V<sub>th</sub>, I do:

$$V_{th} = 30V * \frac{705.88}{705.88 + 100} = 26.28V$$

I know that's wrong (I have the solution to this problem), but how do I really figure it out?

For R<sub>th</sub>, I shorted out V<sub>s</sub>, and figured out that ((R1 || R2) + R3) || R4.

That gives me...

$$((R1 || R2) + R3) || R4) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{((\frac{1}{\frac{1}{100\Omega} + \frac{1}{1000\Omega}}) + 1500\Omega)} + \frac{1}{900\Omega}}  = 574.8 \Omega $$

which actually comes out correctly!

Thanks in advance

Comment: The 'Vth' you've worked out is the voltage across R2. Now apply a voltage divider with R3 and R4 to get Vth=Vab

Comment: Do you understand what @Chu wrote? You are working through things pretty well, but you just need to apply what he wrote here. You are almost there. Does it make sense?

Comment: The voltage I calculated above was all the resistors, I think the voltage across R2 is 27.27.  Can I just treat this as 2 voltage dividers? If R2 is 27.27 and then calculating the votage across R4 I get 10.22, but the answer in the solution I have is 9.85V.

Comment: But your question says you've calculated 26.28V, not 27.27V,  and \$\frac{900}{900+1500}\times 26.28 = 9.86\: V\$, as required!

Comment: ... 27.27V is wrong

Comment: 26.28V is the voltage I incorrectly calculated for R4.

Comment: I had combined R2, R3, and R4 into one effective resistance of 705.88 Ohms, and then used those in series with R1 as a voltage divider.  That is what gave me the 26.28V.

I think it was an accident that this math works out as a voltage divider when using the R3 + R4 and this 26.28 value.

Comment: Yes, but it happens to be the correct voltage across R2. Just start the analysis again - you're going around in circles now. The mistake you made was calculating the voltage across R2 and then assuming incorrectly that this was Vab

Comment: I didn't do that or assume that.  As I said, the 26.28V value is the voltage I calculated incorrectly across R4 per the analysis I gave in the original answer.  I'm totally lost.

Comment: Your equation that starts: \$ V_{th}= 30 ...\$, is actually the voltage across R2//(R3+R4), whether you intended it or not! Now you need to calculate the voltage across R4, which you can get from the voltage divider formed by R3 and R4.

Comment: I'm just not clear why I needed to multiply by $$\frac{900}{900+1500}$$ to get the V<sub>th</sub>.  I was thinking V<sub>th</sub> was 26.28.  

I think my understanding of which resistors are in series and parallel in the circuit isn't correct, and my original analysis is totally wrong it was just an accident that I got a correct value for R2.

Comment: The voltage at the junction of R1, R2, and R3 is 26.28V. Now you can consider R3 and R4 to be a voltage divider with 26.28V across the ends, hence the voltage across R4 is: \$ \frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4}\times 26.28\$

Comment: Why is the voltage there that value? I calculated the value by accident. I don't understand why we're ending up using the value of r3 twice. Once in the calculation of 26.28 and again as a voltage divider with R4

Comment: ... perhaps if you re-draw the circuit with the series combination of R3 and R4 vertical and clearly in parallel with R2, things might be clearer.

Comment: Ah yes thank you! The effective resistance from the node after R1 is the 705 ohms I calculated. I still needed to take into account the voltage divider by R3 and R4, and now I see why. Thanks again for your patience!!

Comment: No problem, glad you've got it now.

Comment: Hint: (1) transform Thevenin source into Norton source (2) integrate next parallel resistor into new Norton source (3) transform last Norton source into a Thevenin source (4) integerate next series resistance into another new Thevenin source (5) repeat with step (1)

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to give another way of calculating the desired voltage by finding a Norton equivalent, which in result simplifies the circuit and should give you no trouble.

Find the current that goes through ab by short-circuiting the R4 resistor (remove it from the circuit and just place a wire instead of it). You have already found the thevenin resistance so you just have to find the current through ab (which has no R4 resistor) and multiply the two. $$I_{ab}R_e=V_T$$ I find this the easiest way of solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a fresh look at the network. The voltage across a-b is the voltage across across R4. While you have calculated the total network resistance, that does not directly relate to the voltage across R4.

I am stopping short of giving you the answer. If you need further assistance, indicate so in the comments to this question and I will elaborate further.

Comment: I'm still not sure, can you help me understand the effect of the resistors on the voltage here? I'm just doing problems from http://tuttle.merc.iastate.edu/ee201/practice/thevenin/thevenin.php, and there's a ton of them that are like this.

I thought originally, I could treat this as 2 voltage dividers, but I end up with 10.22V across R4 instead of the solution of 9.85V.  It seems close, but I'm missing something in my calculation there.

Answer (score 0):

The resistance you have calculated just gives the voltage remaining after drop at  resistor R1. But the Rth is not that one because there is still one resistor in series (i.e R3) within the resistance you have calculated. So you have to subtract the effect of R3 which will give you the voltage across R4 which is also the required Rth. 
Hope this one helps.....

Answer (score 0):

I think the **easiest** way to *intuitively* solve this, is by determining the Thevenin equivalent in two steps, like so:

First you solve the Thevenin equivalent for Vs, R1 and R2 only

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyGayA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the first stage, you find that

$$V_{th1} = \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}V_s$$
$$R_{th1} = R1||R2$$

In the second stage, you find the *actual* Thevenin equivalent from the intermediate one.

$$V_{th} = \frac{R4}{R_{th1} + R_3 + R_4}V_{th1}$$
$$R_{th} = (R_{th1} + R_3) || R_4$$

The **second** way of solving this, is what I consider the "general" way of solving it: by using KCL or KVL laws to find the Thevenin voltage. This should always work, but it is also the most tedious. Using KCL laws, calling the middle voltage \$v_1\$, you can find that

$$\begin{align}
&in\ v_1)\quad& \frac{v_1 - V_s}{R_1} + \frac{v_1}{R_2} + \frac{v_1 - V_{th}}{R_3} &= 0 \\
&in\ V_{th})\quad& \frac{V_{th} - v_1}{R_3} + \frac{V_{th}}{R_4} &= 0
\end{align}$$

A **third** way of solving this, is by using the [EET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_element_theorem) (Extra Element Theorem). In which case you can leave out one element to find the output voltage almost immediately. For example, using R2 as the extra element, you can find \$R_d\$ and \$R_n\$ by leaving it out, making the schematic much easier.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{V_{th}}{V_s} &= H_\infty\frac{1 + \frac{R_n}{R}}{1 + \frac{R_d}{R}} \\
&= \frac{R_4}{R_1 + R_3 + R_4}\cdot \frac{1 + \frac{0}{R_2}}{1 + \frac{R_1 || (R_3 + R_4)}{R_2}} \\
&\Downarrow \\
V_{th} &= \frac{R_4}{R_1 + R_3 + R_4}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{R_1 || (R_3 + R_4)}{R_2}} V_s
\end{align}$$

I have to admit that it takes a little while to get used to this method, but it can certainly pay off in some cases.